# How to count the number of tweets for each label in the dataset and then split data by labels (java)?

Tags: java, counting

This is my code, and it splits data into sentences. Each sentence is labeled with an emotion. I need to count the number of sentences for each label (emotion) and split the dataset according to labels.

```
public class DataProcessor {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        try (Scanner read = new Scanner (new File("E:\\blabla.txt"))) {
            read.useDelimiter("::");
            String tweet;
            while(read.hasNext())
            {
                tweet = read.next();            
                System.out.println(tweet + " "+ "\n"); //just for debugging
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output looks like this

joy:
Had a test today. But I still was good

Comment: Your output has more than one sentence? - so is each sentence labeled with a single emotion or not?

Comment: They are tweets from twitter, so you are right, some of them contain 2 sentences. But each tweet is labeled with a single emotion. Tweets are separated with "::" in my dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    HashMap<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    try (Scanner read = new Scanner (new File("E:\\blabla.txt"))) {
        read.useDelimiter("::");
        String tweet;
        while(read.hasNext())
        {
            tweet = read.next();
            String[] split = tweet.split(":");
            String key = split[0];
            if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
                map.put(key, new ArrayList<>());
            }
            map.get(key).add(split[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

The `map` contains all emotions with sentences. To get the number of sentences, lets call them tweets because sometimes they contain more than one, you can use `map.get("joy").size()`.

If the tweet also can contain `:` I would change `tweet.split(":");` to `tweet.split(":", 2);` so that only the first delimiter is used to split.

To check the result `map` you can use this code:

```
map.forEach((e, t) -> {
    System.out.println(e);
    t.forEach(System.out::println);
} );
```